# Using datalist header template

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I have two tables named as `tbl_catagories` and `tbl_subcatagories`....
`tbl_catagory` have two columns:

```
1.Cat_id.  
2.Cat_name.
```

`tblSubcatagory` has 3 columns in which cat_id is a foreign key in that

```
1.Sub_id  
2.Cat_id foreign key.  
3.Sub_name.
```

What I want in datalist  is  the name of  the `catagory` n the `subcatagory` it have....

```
Like   
Computers  
1.desktops  
2.Laptops.  
Books  
1.Adventure.  
3.Romance.
```

Like this link have

http://www.olx.in/?from=www

please help me to figure it out.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below one helps.
It also has a similar scenario for creating xml files.

Just check it.

http://www.tomasvera.com/programming/generating-hierarchical-nested-xml-from-a-dataset/